# using randbetween function with maximum random numbers 20

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Is there a way to generate random number between 1-5 with the condition of maximum 5s in a range of cells (say A1 - A15) should be 10.

that is, when I drag the cells to copy the formula to other cells, if there are already 10 number of 5s, the random number generation should stop putting 5s in cells.
I found following formula which works to get the random numbers between 1-5, but I don't know how to modify it to do above action. Do anyone know how to do such a action? if it can't be done in formula level, may be a vba script etc? or any word or phrase that I should google?

```
=randbetween(1,5)
```

Answer (score 3):

Starting your data from A2 enter this formula:
`=RANDBETWEEN(1,4+(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,5)<5))`

This won't put any more `5` after five of it had occurred.

[image]

Comment: I REALLY like the approach of using a Boolean within `RANDBETWEEN()`

Comment: Very clever. +1  Technically, though, the maximum count is 10 rather than 5.

Comment: @MátéJuhász : this formula just puts "0" in the cell, I think the formula has errors.

Comment: it works for me (please see screenshot), please note that you need to start your formula in 2nd row, otherwise you'll get circular reference there. If you need number in first row too, simply use `RANDBETWEEN(1,5)` there.

Comment: THAT, that is a clever one. Nice!